# Printing a map inside a vector

Tags: c++, vector

How to print a map inside a vector. I'm finding for a solution here but couldn't find one.

```
std::vector< std::map<std::string, std::string> > output_map_vector;
```

Comment: Step 1: learn how to print from a `vector`. Step 2: learn how to print from a map. Step 3: combine those two things. It's no different to trying to print a `vector<int>`

Comment: Per the downvote tooltip: _This question does not show any research effort_.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
for(const auto &v: output_map_vector)
for(const auto &kv: v)
  std::cout<<kv.first<<" "<<kv.second<<std::endl;
```

Or

```
for(auto v=output_map_vector.begin();v!=output_map_vector.end();v++)
for(auto kv=v->begin();kv!=v->end();kv++)
  std::cout<<(kv->first)<<" "<<kv->second<<std::endl;
```

Comment: My compiler is below c++11. Thank you btw

Comment: @Gelo: I've edited my answer to show the use of iterators. But if your compiler can't handle C++11, you probably need a new compiler.